# AbstractFactory pattern but some functions in ConcreteObjects are really the same

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am new in design patterns and wanted to do a simple AbstractFactory pattern in Python

My question would be, how should I handle some functions between two Concrete objects that are the same for now but could change in the future?

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractFactory(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_func(self):
        pass

class ConcreteObject1(AbstractFactory):
    def some_func(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class ConcreteObject2(AbstractFactory):
    def some_func(self, x, y):
        return x + y
```

For now, `some_func` should really be implemented the same but could change in the future. Is it a good practice to design it like this even if they're the same now?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be OK if you handled it something like the following:

You can give the abstract method in the base class an implementation that derived class methods can call via `super()` to use some default definition. That way the method can stay abstract with a minimal amount of repetitive boilerplate code in each subclass. This is even noted in the [`abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) documentation at the end.

Seems like a reasonable way to do things if you think you might want to force subclasses to really implement it someday. You could even change the base class implementation to raise an exception if it's ever called should you decide to make writing one a requirement.

Here's what I mean:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class AbstractFactory(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_func(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class ConcreteFactory1(AbstractFactory):
    def some_func(self, x, y):
        return super().some_func(x, y)


class ConcreteFactory2(AbstractFactory):
    def some_func(self, x, y):
        return super().some_func(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    obj1 = ConcreteFactory1()
    print(obj1.some_func(1, 42))  # -> 43
```

Comment: AbstractFactory pattern seems to be really verbose, right? If I do this, there will be a lot of functions under the `AbstractFactory` class

Comment: Yes, it's an inherently (inheirently? ;¬) verbose pattern. Note in this [UML class diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Abstract_factory_UML.svg) for `AbstractFactory`, how each `ConcreteFactory` has to implement *all* the `abstractmethod`s defined in their `AbstractFactory` base class.